# Using a variable in page permalink

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm trying to alter some of my pages permalink by adding a variable in the permalink, it works for changing the permalink, but the link gets 404 error.

My page permalink:

```
https://example.com/top_in_YEAR_NAME
```

My function:

```
add_filter('page_link', function($link) {
    return str_replace('YEAR_NAME', '2023', $link);
});
```

As I said, the permalink changes from `YEAR_NAME` to `2023`, but the link gets 404 error.

Is there something missing?

Comment: Yes, that year value invalidates the permalink because the post slug no longer matches the one in the database, so you'd want to add the rewrite rule for handling that year value. Is this for parent Pages only, or also child ones (e.g. at `example.com/parent-page/child-page`)?

Comment: It's for the parent page (no child page). I tried the following rewrite rules but didn't work:
add_action('init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('top_in_2023', 'index.php?post_name=top_in_YEAR_NAME', 'top' );
});

Comment: That's because you should use `pagename` for Pages (post type `page`) and not `post_name`, and you may also have forgotten to flush the rewrite rules. And actually, I wondered how did you make the `top_in_YEAR_NAME` as your post slug, because by default, WordPress will convert uppercase letters to lowercase.. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I said, the permalink changes from `YEAR_NAME` to `2023`, but the
> link gets 404 error

Yes, and it's because the post slug no longer matched the value in the database (in the `wp_posts` table, column `post_name`), hence the permalink URL became invalid and WordPress displayed a 404 error page.

So you need to add a rewrite rule for handling the year value which replaces the `TOP_NAME` in the slug.

Here's an example you can try, and you can change the `^top_in_2023` with `^top_in_\d{4}` instead so that it matches *any 4-digit year*:

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^top_in_2023',
        // for Pages, the query var is pagename
        'index.php?pagename=top_in_YEAR_NAME',
        'top'
    );
} );
```

Remember to flush the rewrite rules, by simply visiting the Permalink Settings admin page.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you. But is the ^ needed here for this case?

Comment: Not really, but just in case :) Also, can you answer my question on how did you make WordPress accept the uppercase `YEAR_NAME` in your post slug? Did you use a plugin?

Comment: I didn't actually. I typed it as an uppercase here just for the sake of clarity. :)

Comment: One last thing please, what if I want to replace 'top_in_2023' with a regex? Just to replace 'YEAR_NAME' with 2023, no matter the other part of the permalink is.

Comment: I mean I don't want to use 'top_in_'. I want it that simple: find CURRENT_YEAR in the permalink replace it with 2023. Something like str_replace('CURRENT_YEAR', 2023, $permalink), but in add_rewrite_rule function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142838/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-user1181378).